# One iteration is being wasted, and not getting proper output. (Python)

Tags: python

I am beginner in python and trying to make a simple game in which the user has to guess the word/name by inputting characters of that word/name. The program will generate stars of the word length which the user has to guess.

When the user will input a character, the position of that character in stars will be changed to that character. For example, The word is my name "Vishwas", the program will generate 7 stars as the length of my name is 7, `*******`, when user will input `i` the output will be `Correct *i*****` like this.

Now the problem is my name has two 's' in it, the program is okay till 2 's' but when we input third 's' as input it just wastes that iteration, I want here output as "Incorrect" which I just don't know how to fix here otherwise all the code is okay.

Also, tell what function to use to let the program wait till the user inputs a character as C++ has `getch` function right now I have used time function.

```
import time
print("\t\t\t\t\t\t\tWelcome to name guessing game")
name = "shahzaib"
LengthOfWord = len(name)
stars = []
for x in range(LengthOfWord):
    stars.append("*")
stars = ''.join(stars)
print(stars)
print("Enter a character")
chance = 2
y=0
LOW=LengthOfWord
while y < LOW:
    if chance<0:
        print("Game Over")
        break
    chr = input()
    chr = chr.lower()
    count = 0
    for x in range(LengthOfWord):
        if chr[0] == name[x]:
            if stars[x] == name[x]:
                continue
            else:
                stars = list(stars)
                stars[x] = chr[0]
                stars = ''.join(stars)
                print("Correct\n",stars)
            if stars == name:
                print("Congratulations you won")
            break
        count+=1
        if count == LengthOfWord:
            print("Incorrect\n",chance,"Chance(s) left\n",stars)
            chance -= 1
            LOW=LOW+1
    y+=1
time.sleep(3)
```

The program is pretty simple I think it should be easily understandable.

Comment: Your code is too much completed, try to simplify it a bit, make efficient use of variables rather than making unnecessary new declarations. Once simplified you will figure out what should u do

Comment: @ZainArshad I can't simplify it more, I tried my best and this is the last result which you can see.

Comment: Change range(LengthOfWord) to range(LengthOfWord+1) in for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is too much complex, you don't have to use any `time` class to wait for user to input, in python we use `input()` simple. It will wait till infinity for user to input something.

This can be done simply like this:

```
name = 'shahzaib'
chances = 3
stars = ['*' for _ in name]  # I kept it as a list so that we can replace * with char
print("\t\tWelcome to name guessing game")

# while there are chances and user hasn't guessed the whole name
while chances > 0 and '*' in stars:
    user = input("\nEnter Character: ").lower()

    # If correct
    if user in name:
        index = name.find(user)  # find the first occurence of that char in name
        name = name.replace(user, '.', 1)  # now replace that char with some special character like '.'
        stars[index] = user  # replace the value in the stars list so that we can show it to the user
        print("Correct\nName: " + ''.join(stars))
    else:
        chances -=1 
        print("Incorrect, {} chances left.".format(chances))
```

Your problem is when you have more than 1 occurrence of the same character in name. This problem arose because of your logic.

The solution as you can see is to replace the occurrence of the character with some special letter like `. , :, ;` etc, that will not be used in a name. This will also make the program more elegant as you will be guessing the character from left to right.

Ask me anything if you feel confused about the code.

Comment: I still have some problems in list, loops and functions in python, but I am on learning stage that's why my logic was so bad.